# Upper Triangular Matrix Basis Interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

What does it mean for a matrix to be UT with respect to some basis? In the sense, what does it imply about the basis being used or about the matrix? Is there a analogy to the eigenvalue case where the basis has a very clear meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis for $V$. For $1\le k\le n$ write $V_k$ for
the span of $v_1,\ldots,v_k$. Then $V_1\subset V_2\subset\cdots\subset V_n=V$
and $\dim V_k=k$. Such a chain of subspaces is called a *flag*. Then a linear map $T:V\to V$ is triangular with respect to the basis if $T(V_k)\subseteq V_k$
for each $k$. That is, the triangular matrices represent the transformations
preserving the flag.

Comment: Ok, I get you point. But how is this kind of a thing useful? Eigenvectors tell us something fundamental about a transform, what about this? This also means that UT matrices are non-unique right as many combinations would satisy : 1⊂2⊂⋯⊂ ?

Answer (score 1):

If your vector space $V$ is $n$-dimensional, then define a *flag* to be a sequence of subspaces
$$V_0\subset V_1\subset \cdots \subset V_n$$
where $V_i$ has dimension $i$.

(Therefore, necessarily, $V_0$ is the zero subspace and $V_n$ is all of $V$.)

Say that a linear transformation *preserves* the flag if it takes each $V_i$ into itself.

Then a linear transformation can be triangularized if and only if it preserves some flag.

(Sketch of proof:  Pick a $v_1$ that spans $V_1$, a $v_2$ so that $v_1$ and $v_2$ span $V_2$, a $v_3$ so that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ span $V_3$, etc; then transform to this basis.)

Comment: And it looks like @LordShark and I were typing pretty much simultaneously......

Comment: Ok, I get you point. But how is this kind of a thing useful? Eigenvectors tell us something fundamental about a transform, what about this? This also means that UT matrices are non-unique right as  many combinations would satisy : 0⊂1⊂⋯⊂ ?